# SP2010 psconfig fails trying to configure farm after installing language packs

Tags: language, configuration

I'm using the AutoSPInstaller script. This is what I run:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $PSConfig -ArgumentList "-cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -passphrase FarmPassPhrase -force -wait" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

But I get a bunch of errors:

```
Performing configuration task 3 of 4
Upgrading SharePoint Products...
Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.

Total number of configuration settings run: 3
Total number of successful configuration settings: 2
Total number of unsuccessful configuration settings: 1
Successfully stopped the configuration of SharePoint Products.
Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.
```

The PSCDiagnostics Log has the following errors:

```
03/03/2011 09:35:25  8  ERR            Exception:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPUpgradeSession Name=Upgrade-20110303-113635-252 was updated by NA\myID, in the PSCONFIG (3644) process, on machine SHAREPOINT.  View the tracing log for more information about the conflict.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.StoreObject(SPPersistedObject obj, Boolean storeClassIfNecessary, Boolean ensure)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.PutObject(SPPersistedObject persistedObject, Boolean ensure)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Update()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ContinueOnLocalThread(Guid id, Boolean consoleOutput)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.ContinueSessionOnLocalThread(Guid id, Boolean consoleOutput)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
...
03/03/2011 09:35:25  1  ERR      Post setup configuration was not run successfully when using the command line task driver module
```

Does anybody have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: If the problem is AutoSpInstaller relater, you should ask the question on Codeplex not here

Comment: Have you retried running psconfig or viewing the tracing log to see the conflict as per the note in the diagnostic log?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following commands and managed to successfully run the upgrade

```
PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```